# Where are the official Ruby 1.9 Docker Images?

Tags: ruby, docker, dockerfile, ruby-1.9.3

I ran the following Docker command from a Git Bash shell on Windows 10:

`docker pull ruby:1.9.3`

to get the following output (I removed a couple lines for clarity):

```
1.9.3: Pulling from library/ruby
...
Digest: sha256:c296bd581b8c1ee0585a77cafc0b14342356cea30a10fa2c9f82370909665149
Status: Image is up to date for ruby:1.9.3
```

So it looks like everything "just worked" and I've now got a Ruby 1.9.3 Docker image.

**But where did this image come from?**  When I look at `library/ruby` at [Docker Hub](https://hub.docker.com/_/ruby/) or at the associated [GitHub repo](https://github.com/docker-library/ruby), I don't see any mention of a `1.9.3` tag.  There are numerous third-party images on Docker Hub targeting Ruby 1.9.3, and I'm concerned that I've downloaded one of them rather than an "official" image from the Ruby or Docker teams.  I'd also like to find this image's source so I can see what's in its Dockerfile.  Is this image just not mentioned in the official pages linked above?  I'm quite new to the Ruby world so any input helps!

Comment: @SergioTulentsev I actually tried `docker inspect` but didn't know what any of the output meant.  I didn't see any URLs indicating where the image came from

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's actually available, but not visible in Dockerhub:

You can see it via the API:

https://hub.docker.com/v2/repositories/library/ruby/tags/1.9.3/

The fact that it pulls from `library/x`, means that it's an official version.

Comment: thanks for the link!  I figured `library/x` was official, just wanted to be sure.  Any idea where I could find the Dockerfile for that image?

Comment: I went back to the very first commit in the Github and found it there: looks like the 1.9 images' Dockerfiles have been deleted since: https://github.com/docker-library/ruby/blob/4938a7b4b5b62c90b5d387c9c286fd7749d9499e/1.9/Dockerfile

Comment: Wow, very thorough, thanks for looking into this!  I think that's enough to point me in the right direction